# Notifications wont work Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

i've implemented notifications on my app.And they were working fine until yesterday out of the blue the stopped working.now when i click on the route that enables the notification it just keeps loading this is the store method on my controller where i check if the email notifications are enabled and if they are the user should recieve an email everytime a project is published

```
public function store(Request $request){

$this->validate(request(), [
    'title'    => 'required|max:255|unique:projects',
    'body'     => 'required|max:1000',
    // 'tutorial' => 'required|max:1000',
    'avatar'   => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png',
    'zip_file' => 'required|mimes:zip,rar',
]);
$user = User::all();
$profiles_storage = storage_path('app/avatars/');
$project =  new Project;
$project -> user_id = auth()->id();
$project -> title = request('title');
$project -> body = request('body');
$project -> tutorial = request('tutorial');
$project -> views = '0';
$project -> downloads = '0';
$project -> alternative_text = config('app.name').' '.request('title').' '.'project';
$profile = request()->file('avatar');
// $profile->store('profiles');
$project->image = $profile->hashName();
$image = Image::make($profile->getRealPath());
$image->fit(640, 360, function ($constraint) 
{ $constraint->upsize();})->save($profiles_storage.$profile->hashName());



request()-> file('zip_file')->store('zip_files');
$project -> zip_file = request()->file('zip_file')->hashName();
$project -> save();
$category = $request->input('categories');
$project->categories()->sync($category);
foreach ($user as $u) {
    if ($u->email_notifications != 0) {
    $u->notify(new ProjectPublished($project));
}
}

session()->flash('message',"{$project->title}".' created');
return redirect('/admin/projects');


}
```

and this is the ProjectPublished.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\User; use App\Project; use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification; use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue; use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ProjectPublished extends Notification { use Queueable; protected $project;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Project $project)
{
    $this->project = $project;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{       
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello there')
                ->subject('New Project:'.$this->project->title)
                ->line('As requested we are letting you know that a new project was published at Rek Studio')
                ->action('Check it out', url('projects/'.$this->project->title));
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does general emailing work from within the app or is it also not working?

Comment: no nothing is working it just keeps loading

Comment: I don't mean on this route, I mean in general, is your email configuration correct on the server?

Comment: everything is correct and was working fine till yesterday.but today when i click the route the page just keeps loading and does nothing until it says maximum time of execution exceded